# $LC$ Circuit: differential equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, capacitance, inductance

A capacitance of 200nF can, for example, stand for an overhead line with no load at the end. It lies in what we call idle time. The voltage source and the inductance can represent a net behind. It will also have a resistance R, but we ignore this because
the charging current is not that great. The frequency f is 50Hz. Assume that the voltage $U = \sqrt{2} \cdot 24 \, \text{kV}$

(1) We assume that the switch is on. Calculate the reactance values ​​and find the charging current. Is the circuit capacitive or inductive? Show that the voltage across the capacitance can be slightly larger than the source voltage $U$. (This is called the Ferranti effect and means that we can get a voltage rise beyond overhead lines with light load. This is primarily done applicable at the highest voltage levels where we may have long overhead lines.

(I manage to find the expression that describes the voltage source and the current. But I cannot find the expression for the voltage of the capacitor. I know I have to use differential equation to solve it)

[image]

(2) The returning voltage across the switch poles (the voltage between
the capacitance and point A) after breakdown can be approximately expressed as: $$U_{\text{switch}}(t) = \sqrt{2} \cdot U \left(1 - \cos(wt)\right)$$ Derive this expression.